# Yii2: How to change language of a page with parameters?

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a website with yii2 and want to allow the web pages to be displayed in different languages. So I created some hyperlinks to change the language of the website.

I have set some url rules to make it look better. And I used the `Url::to(['controller/action', 'lang'=>$lang])` function in layout/main.php to refresh the page. It actually changed the language but it didn't work on some pages which require more parameters (it will redirect to the error page).

The main.php is a shared template for all pages and I have many pages with different parameters required. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Read this [guide](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md), there are some good instructions how to handle language changing in Yii 2.